# Reason for handlebar diameter

Tags: handlebars

Why are handlebars the diameter they are ([22.2 or 23.8 in grip area](http://sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-handlebars.html))? In general, the best diameter for grip strength is where the hand around the grip has about 1mm from the tip of the middle finger to the palm (this rule is used to select tennis racquet grip diameter for example). Sounds like the usual handlebar diameter is too narrow for optimal grip for most people, even with thick wrapping tape. Any reason for this?

Comment: How hard go you think you need to grip a handlebar?

Comment: Not hard, but the optimal grip diameter makes any grip less tiring.

Comment: Then maybe they were not designing for optimal grip. Aerodynamics?

Comment: The effect on aerodynamics is [very small](http://www.tri-guru.com/art15.htm). And most bikes are not for racing, so grip comfort would be more important than aerodynamics.

Comment: More important to you.  They modify the shape of a seat post for aerodynamics.

Comment: More important to the average rider. More important to the biggest market. Also me, but I don't think the manufacturers focus on me.

Comment: You do have a point, in that the weight of your body on the handlebar causes pain due to poor blood circulation and pressure on the nerves.  However, I once calculated that the bar would need to be 3-4 inches in diameter to totally alleviate this issue.  The better way to alleviate pain is to change hand positions frequently and/or have ribbed handlebar covers.  There is no great need to grip the handlebar tightly -- there is no significant torque at the grip, unlike a racket.

Comment: So you know for a fact aerodynamics is not even design consideration.  The only design consideration is grip and they all got that wrong?

Comment: Just to back up @Blam's point a bit, the aerodynamics would have been approximated, guessed or assumed at the time standards were set, so the small effect we can calculate or measure now may have been taken to be larger. Without a compelling reason to change the diameter of the actual metal it is likely to stay the same.

Comment: @ChrisH - There is no real "standard" for handlebar diameter.  Some sizes are, I suppose, "habitual" (and "blessed" by ISO), but new sizes are introduced at the whim of the manufacturers.  The fact that there's not a wider variety of sizes is mostly due to the fact that there's no compelling "story" for new ones.

Comment: Historic reason. Tubing was made in that diameter. Stems were made to fit. Pre WWII bars fit stems from the '70s.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, perhaps "standards" is too strong but "habit" and the range of grips for flat bar bikes come to the same thing in practice.

Comment: In fact handlebars are made from a much thicker tubing which is *butted* to the narrow diameter, while leaving the wider clamp diameter in the center (which is now a whopping 31-something mm nowadays: much thicker than the rest of the bar). If thicker were better, then less butting could be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to consider how people use the handlebars. e.g. covering the brakes -- could someone with small hands reach the brakes easily with an optimal-for-the-average-person diameter (I suspect not, especially with the brakes of many years ago when standards were set).  Also if pure grip comfort were the issue, drop bars wouldn't have happened; instead they are optimised for a range of positions for different situations and to allow the rider to vary their body position for several reasons.

It's easier to take a thin bar and make it thicker by double wrapping or padded gloves, but if your bars were too thick (small hands) they would have to be replaced, reducing the market for standard bikes.

Flat bar bikes tend to have grips with some thickness to them, taking them closer to the optimal while still allowing the rider to cover/use the brakes for long periods without contortions or spoiling the grip you'd need over rough terrain.

The exact numbers are a matter of convention, which may derive from imperial measurements, a round number minus a fixed thickness, or a combination of the 2 -- this is well documented for tyre sizing as a comparison.

*This was a comment before I expanded and formatted it.*